# iPad Safari Delete Website Data

Tags: iphone, safari, ipad, youtube

Off late, the Safari on my iPad has become a bit slow. That is, the pages take a long time to load.

Would deleting Website Data help in improving the speed ? Or any other options ?

It would be great if my form autocomplete data and website history (shown in address bar) do not get deleted. I guess the Clear History/Cookies would do that.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the settings application.
Select Safari from the left bar, from there you can press "Clear Cookies and Data"

It will not clear your history.

But cleaning cookies will make you login again to web sites you use.

You can go to Advanced, Website Data to see which sites store information on your iPad (mostly cookies).

Comment: Which option would preserver my form autocomplete data and address bar urls?